# Does saxon support parameters in an XPath/XQuery?

Tags: java, saxon

In saxon is it possible to have a query like:

```
//root/employees/employee[@id = $var]
```

And pass in a map or something with `{$var, 23}`

If so, can you please point me to a sample?

Followup question (what's the actual Java code) [posted here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253546/how-do-i-set-a-variable-in-an-xpath-query-in-saxon-on-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular expression is valid in both XPath and XQuery.

With the s9api interface:

- In XPath, variables are declared by calling `XPathCompiler.declareVariable()` before you compile the query, or you can also permit undeclared variables by calling `XPathCompiler.setAllowUndeclaredVariables()`. Values for parameters are supplied by calling `XPathSelector.setVariable()`.
- In XQuery, parameters must be declared in the Query Prolog. (`declare variable $var external;`). Values for parameters are supplied using `XQueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable()`