# How do I set a variable in an XPath query in Saxon on Java

Tags: java, saxon

The following code returns 4 nodes (using [southwind.xml](https://cdn.windwardstudios.com/Southwind/SouthWind.xml) & [southwind.xsd](https://cdn.windwardstudios.com/Southwind/SouthWind.xsd)):

```
XPathExecutable exec = datasource.getxPathCompiler().compile("/windward-studios/Employees/Employee[@EmployeeID < 5]");
XPathSelector selector = exec.load();
selector.setContextItem(datasource.getXmlRootNode());
XdmValue nodeSet = selector.evaluate();
```

But the following returns 0 nodes:

```
datasource.getxPathCompiler().declareVariable(new QName("p1"));
XPathExecutable exec = datasource.getxPathCompiler().compile("/windward-studios/Employees/Employee[@EmployeeID < p1]");
XPathSelector selector = exec.load();
selector.setContextItem(datasource.getXmlRootNode());
selector.setVariable(new QName("p1"), new XdmAtomicValue(5));
XdmValue nodeSet = selector.evaluate();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
It looks like it needs a $ sign:

```
compile("/windward-studios/Employees/Employee[@EmployeeID < $p1]");
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable references in XPath and XSLT start with `$`, so `$p1` is the right way in XPath to reference the variable named `p1`. Your previous attempt `p1` would select an element node named `p1`.